# The F7 key is not recognized in the KeyDown Event

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010

In the KeyDown Event of my Silverlight TextBox Control, the <kbd>F7</kbd> key is not being recognized and I have not been able to figure out why.

Code here:

```
  private void txtDraw_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.Key == Key.F7)
      {
          Debug.WriteLine("F7");
          drawRect();
      }
      else if (e.Key == Key.F8)
      {
          Debug.WriteLine("F8");
          draw2Rects();
      }
      else if (e.Key == Key.F9)
      {
          Debug.WriteLine("F9");
          draw3Rects();
      }
  }

    private void draw3Rects()
    {

    }

    private void draw2Rects()
    {

    }

    private void drawRect()
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(red);
        Grid.SetColumn(rect, 1);
        Grid.SetRow(rect, 0);
    }
```

I know that pressing the <kbd>F7</kbd> key is not doing anything, because I have tried debugging at that line and I have tried doing a Debug.WriteLine(). The only Debug.WriteLine() methods that occur are when the <kbd>F8</kbd> key and <kbd>F9</kbd> key are pressed. <kbd>F7</kbd> doesn't work.

In Internet Explorer 32 bit, the <kbd>F7</kbd> key is reserved for a particular function (I think it was Caret Browsing). I have not found how to change it and I can probably not change it.

One thing I could speculate is that Internet Explorer might be stealing the KeyDown Event when the <kbd>F7</kbd> key is pressed. I don't know how those two processes are isolated.

Any ideas why the <kbd>F7</kbd> key is not recognized?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open connect issue about the wider problem of certain key combinations not being exposed, because the browser recieves them first.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/525760/silverlight-in-ie8-ctrl-p-and-some-other-ctrl-shortcuts-cannot-catched

At present the connect item has 7 votes and the SL program manager has responded by saying this is by design - so doesn't look hopeful.